# When does a set generate a vector space?

Tags: vector-spaces

What kind of set would generate $R^n$ ? What about $P_n$ ?
Also, the exam question that made me ask this:

> Does the set $S = \{1, x^2, x^2 + 2\}$ generates $P_2$ ?

I'm a little bit uncertain about when does a set generates a vector space, therefore I can't figure out if it does or not.

Comment: Can every vector in $P_2$ be formed as a linear combination of the elements in the set?  For example, can $f(x)=x+1$ be formed as a linear combination of the elements in $S$?

Comment: If that's the answer then no, it's not possible because $v = x^2 + 2x + 1$ is part of $P_2$ and there's no way to get it from that linear combination, due to the lack of a grade one $x$.

Comment: From definition, a set generates a vector space if every element of the vector space can be written as a linear combination of the element of that set. Assuming $P_n$ is the vector space of the polynomials of degree less and equal to n, that set clearly doesn't generate, can you see why?

Comment: @DavideMorgante Indeed. Like I said in my previous comment, the set doesn't generates $P_2$
Thank you everyone. Question answered.

Answer (score 2):

No, the set $S$ does not generate $P_n$. The lack of an $x$ term from any of the polynomials in $S$ means that polynomials such as $x + 1$ and $x^2 + 2x + 1$ cannot be linear combinations of polynomials in $S$.